# How to add and remove CardView from LinearLayout on button click in android studio?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a linear layout that contains a cardView. I want to add and delete cardViews dynamically on button clicks. I have tried the following code but the delete button doesn't work moreover the padding of dynamically added view changes on its own after adding a new as shown in picture below. [image: picture]

**ExperienceInfoActivity.java**

```
package kbg.com.kbgpos.forms;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import kbg.com.kbgpos.R;

public class ExperienceInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private LinearLayout parentRelativeLayout;
    private View v;
    EditText fromDateEditText,toDateEditText;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_experience_info);
        initViews();
        initListeners();
    }


    private void initViews() {
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarExperienceInfoActivity);
        toolbar.setTitle("Employee Experience Info");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBarTitle));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        parentRelativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.experienceDetailsInfoRelLayout);
        CardView experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw = findViewById(R.id.experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        ImageView delRowBtn = findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
        delRowBtn.setTag(experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        params = experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw.getLayoutParams();
        fromDateEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fromDateEditText);
        toDateEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.toDateEditText);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        fromDateEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= fromDateEditText.getRight() - fromDateEditText.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                                int s=monthOfYear+1;
                                String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;
                                fromDateEditText.setText(""+a);
                            }
                        };

                        Time date = new Time();
                        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ExperienceInfoActivity.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
                        d.show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        toDateEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= toDateEditText.getRight() - toDateEditText.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                                int s=monthOfYear+1;
                                String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;
                                toDateEditText.setText(""+a);
                            }
                        };

                        Time date = new Time();
                        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ExperienceInfoActivity.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
                        d.show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onAddField(View view) {
        try{

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.experience_details_row, null);
            if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>1){
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
            ImageView delRowBtn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
            delRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
            rowView.setLayoutParams(params);
            parentRelativeLayout.addView(rowView, parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount());
            EditText employerNameEditText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.employerNameEditText);
            employerNameEditText.requestFocus();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onDelete(View v) {
        try{
            if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>2) {
                CardView cv = (CardView) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                parentRelativeLayout.removeView(cv);
            }else{
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_grey_50));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**experience_details_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/employerNameTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/employerNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:hint="Employer Name" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/designationTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/employerNameTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/designationEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:hint="Designation" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/addressTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/designationTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:hint="Address" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/fromDateTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/addressTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fromDateEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                    android:hint="From Date" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/toDateTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/fromDateTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/toDateEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:hint="To Date"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addDelLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/toDateTextInputLayout">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/addRowBtn"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:onClick="onAddField"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/delRowBtn"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:onClick="onDelete"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**activity_experience_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".forms.ExperienceInfoActivity">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarExperienceInfoActivity"></include>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/personalDetailScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarExperienceInfoActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/experienceDetailsInfoRelLayout"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/experienceInfoActivityFormHeadingCardVw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Experience Details"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/employerNameTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/employerNameEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="Employer Name" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/designationTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/employerNameTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/designationEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="Designation" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/addressTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/designationTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="Address" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fromDateTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addressTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/fromDateEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                            android:hint="From Date" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/toDateTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/fromDateTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/toDateEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:hint="To Date"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/addDelLayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_below="@id/toDateTextInputLayout">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/addRowBtn"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:onClick="onAddField"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/delRowBtn"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:onClick="onDelete"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:background="#e0e0e0"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="SUBMIT"
            android:background="#ffe57f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `v` in `onDelete(View v)` is not the `CardView` that you want to be removed.   
It's the `ImageView` that you click. 
In `onAddField()` do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.experience_details_row, null);
ImageView delRowBtn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
delRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
parentRelativeLayout.addView(rowView, parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount());
```

what the above code does is store the new `CardView` object in `delRowBtn`'s tag.  
 Also I removed `-1` from `parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()` to add the new CardView at the end.  
But the above logic must be applied also to the 1st `CardView` that is already there, so in `onCreate()` add this:

```
CardView experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw = findViewById(R.id.experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
ImageView delRowBtn = findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
delRowBtn.setTag(experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
```

In `onDelete()` do this:

```
CardView cv = (CardView) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
parentRelativeLayout.removeView(cv);
```

what the above code does is retrieves the `CardView` object from `delRowBtn`'s tag and removes it from `parentRelativeLayout`.

The full code of your Activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ExperienceInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private LinearLayout parentRelativeLayout;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
    private int count = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_experience_info);

        CardView experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw = findViewById(R.id.experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        ImageView delRowBtn = findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
        delRowBtn.setTag(experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        params = experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw.getLayoutParams();

        initViews();
        initListeners();
    }

    private void initListeners() {

    }

    private void initViews() {
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarExperienceInfoActivity);
        toolbar.setTitle("Employee Experience Info");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBarTitle));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        parentRelativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.experienceDetailsInfoRelLayout);
    }

    public void onAddField(View view) {
        try{
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.experience_details_row, null);
            ImageView delRowBtn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
            delRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
            rowView.setLayoutParams(params);
            parentRelativeLayout.addView(rowView, parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount());
            EditText employerNameEditText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.employerNameEditText);
            employerNameEditText.requestFocus();
            count++;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onDelete(View v) {
        try{
            if (count == 1) return;
            CardView cv = (CardView) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
            parentRelativeLayout.removeView(cv);
            count--;

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are amazing @mTak . I am really grateful to you. Thanks. I have tried the above code, logical problem of add & delete row have been solved though the padding issue still persists. Please help me with this. Also please do let me know as how can i move focus to new cardview when its added?

Comment: I think that now the padding and focus problem is solved. I posted the full code. Try it.

Comment: I added a suggestion: keep track of the number of cards so that if you have only 1 it will not be deleted. If you don't need it just remove everything that has to do with the variable `count`.

Comment: I have edited my code as you can see above as per your suggestion. But now what i am trying to achieve is that as i click on add button it should be removed from current card and should be added to new card which i am able to do but when only one card is left i am not able to add addRow button again to single left card, plz help. Also, i have added datepicker on fromDateEditText but it works only for first card not for dynamically added cardviews. Could you please guide??

Comment: For the 1st part I really don't understand what you want. For the 2nd part: now as your app needs grow I have to tell you that your approach is wrong. You should have used a list like a recyclerview and not single items that you add or remove. All these new actions that you want to add to the items will be more and more difficult because for each one you'll have to implement them twice. Once for the 1st item and again for all the others. So now that you're still at the beginning I advice you to rethink and redesign. It is these cases that a recyclerview is implementd for.

Comment: I understand what you say but how can I use list as it is user's choice to add or delete. User can add as many similar set of details as he want. If this can be achieved using list plz guide how?

Comment: You can find many tutorials about recyclerview. I just made a search in youtube and found a lot. For your case take a look at this link(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enTvZm9LOGc)

Comment: In this video the person has hard-coded data into model type list but here i want to take input from user not from database or already populated lists.

Comment: It is not possible to find one video/tutorial that will fit all your needs. You must search, study and try. It's a step by step procedure.